# Email icons missing from the Panel after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, indicator, panel, messaging-menu

I have recently upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 and then noticed the usual email icon (little envelope icon) which allowed me to run my Evolution, chat and Thunderbird applications is no longer available. Is there a simple way of getting it back?

Comment: i have the same problem. So but the envelope is away after a restart and it dont comes back, after i restarted Thunderbird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as you started your mail application (e.g. Thunderbird) or set up your accounts in the chat application (e.g. Empathy) the message indicator will magically re-appear:

[image]

To remove items in the message indicator we can do so by running [dconf-editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-editor) [image: Install dconf-editor],  remove the application from the key in `com.canonical.indicator.messages`, and restart our session.