# Cannot remove Evolution indicator

Tags: indicator, evolution

I normally use Thunderbird as my email client, but the other day I accidentally started up evolution.

Now the envelope icon in the indicator area contains information about both Thunderbird and Evolution. Since I'm not using Evolution, I tried to get rid of the Evolution information by uninstalling the evolution-indicator package, but this didn't help. I still have both Thunderbird and Evolution listed when I click the envelope icon. (And, yes, I did restart the computer.)

The /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/ directory only contains Thunderbird and Empathy, not Evolution.

How do I get rid of the Evolution information?

Comment: see my answer there on how to remove the entry again: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449174/email-icons-missing-from-menu-bar-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Beautiful, Takkat! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command on terminal to remove  `evolution` package,

```
sudo apt-get remove evolution
```

Or you may run the below command to remove only the evolution indicator on top-panel,

```
sudo apt-get remove evolution-indicator
```

Comment: As I said in my post, I already removed evolution-indicator, but I still have the problem. Do I really need to remove the entire evolution package?

Comment: Yep. Remove the entire package if you don't want it anymore.